# Terminate and retrieve solution in ILOG after a certain time limit

Tags: java, cplex, ilog

I am using ILOG CPLEX from JAVA and I am running an Integer optimisation problem that takes about 3 days to complete the 0.0%. I need to terminate the program after a certain time limit and obtain a solution for whatever the limit left. Can anyone let me know how to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should run CPLEX with TiLim param:

```
cplex.setParam(IloCplex.DoubleParam.TiLim, your_time_in_seconds)
```