# DropSolve Cplex terminate after T time

Tags: java, cplex, docplexcloud

I am using drop solve for a MIP optimization problem, to generate K solutions.

I would like to terminate after 60 seconds. I use cplex.params[1039] = 60; Also tried cplex.tilim = 60 in my .mod file

But the program doesn't stops.

Found this SO link to do the same in Java, but I am using DropSolve DoCplex Cloud. Using the Java API's
[Terminate and retrieve solution in ILOG after a certain time limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24449622/terminate-and-retrieve-solution-in-ilog-after-a-certain-time-limit)

TIA

Comment: It seems like you're setting the parameter correctly (but perhaps in the wrong place?). It's hard to suggest anything without more details. Can you share the engine log from DropSolve and/or your .mod file?

Comment: You may also get better answers if you ask on the [official IBM forum](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/smart-spaces/94/decision-optimization.html) that is dedicated for questions like this.

Comment: Thanks @rkersh 
I have shared this .mod here https://gist.github.com/chahat/6f5436d59a2d91f58251d242efbb277d . Its the standard diet problem, instead am looking for top k solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered the question on the docplexcloud forum https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/385233/dropsolve-cplex-terminate-after-t-time.html.

The engine respects the parameter settings but the .mod file executes some scripting code after the solve. Execution of that code takes longer than expected but this is beyond the control of the engine and its parameters.